# Remove empty namespace declaration in elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I got a XML which I tranform into another, but after the translation I got some elements that have an empty namespace declaration (`xmlns=""`) which I want to remove.

Secondly I also want to have the `xmlns:xsi` declared in the `InterChangeHead` element.

**INPUT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PostenInterchange type="tag">
    <heInterchangeType>PostenInterchange</heInterchangeType>
    <heVersion>1.4-rev3</heVersion>
    <heTestindicator>1</heTestindicator>
    <InterChangeHead type="tag">
        <heVersion>1</heVersion>
        <heSenderid>SENDID</heSenderid>
        <heRecipientid>RECIPID</heRecipientid>
        <heXmlnsxsi>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"</heXmlnsxsi>
        <heXmlns>"posten.xsd"</heXmlns>
        <Shipment type="tag">
            <heShipmenttype>IMP</heShipmenttype>
            <Shipper type="tag">
                <name>Shipper</name>
            </Shipper>
            <Consignee type="tag">
                <name>Consignee</name>
            </Consignee>
            <GoodsData type="tag">
                <heSequencenumber>2</heSequencenumber>
                <GrossWeight>0.000</GrossWeight>
                <NetWeight>0.660</NetWeight>
            </GoodsData>
        </Shipment>
    </InterChangeHead>
</PostenInterchange>
```

**CURRENT XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy local names -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Rename elements beginning with "he" to elements without the "he" -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring(local-name(), 1, 2) = 'he'">
                <xsl:element name="{substring(local-name(), 3)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Correct InterChangeHead element -->
    <xsl:template match="InterChangeHead">
        <xsl:element name="InterChangeHead" namespace="posten.xsd">     
            <!-- Copy childs -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove type attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@type"/>

    <!-- Remove unnecessary elements -->
    <xsl:template match="heXmlnsxsi" />
    <xsl:template match="heXmlns" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PostenInterchange>
    <InterchangeType>PostenInterchange</InterchangeType>
    <Version>1.4-rev3</Version>
    <Testindicator>1</Testindicator>
    <InterChangeHead xmlns="posten.xsd">
        <Version xmlns="">1</Version>
        <Senderid xmlns="">SENDID</Senderid>
        <Recipientid xmlns="">RECIPID</Recipientid>
        <Shipment xmlns="">
            <Shipmenttype>IMP</Shipmenttype>
            <Shipper>
                <name>Shipper</name>
            </Shipper>
            <Consignee>
                <name>Consignee</name>
            </Consignee>
            <GoodsData>
                <Sequencenumber>2</Sequencenumber>
                <GrossWeight>0.000</GrossWeight>
                <NetWeight>0.660</NetWeight>
            </GoodsData>
        </Shipment>
    </InterChangeHead>
</PostenInterchange>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PostenInterchange>
    <InterchangeType>PostenInterchange</InterchangeType>
    <Version>1.4-rev3</Version>
    <Testindicator>1</Testindicator>
    <InterChangeHead xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="posten.xsd" >
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Senderid>SENDID</Senderid>
        <Recipientid>RECIPID</Recipientid>
        <Shipment>
            <Shipmenttype>IMP</Shipmenttype>
            <Shipper>
                <name>Shipper</name>
            </Shipper>
            <Consignee>
                <name>Consignee</name>
            </Consignee>
            <GoodsData>
                <Sequencenumber>2</Sequencenumber>
                <GrossWeight>0.000</GrossWeight>
                <NetWeight>0.660</NetWeight>
            </GoodsData>
        </Shipment>
    </InterChangeHead>
</PostenInterchange>
```

Can anyone help me out with the last bit? I added the next template because I thought this will remove the empty namespace declaration:

```
<!-- Copy local names -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that an `xmlns="..."` declaration sets the default namespace for the element to which it is attached *and all its descendants* unless countermanded by another `xmlns="..."` further down the tree.  Therefore in your desired output all the descendant elements under `<InterChangeHead xmlns="posten.xsd" >` are also in the `posten.xsd` namespace, and your templates need to reflect this.  Since you're using XSLT 2.0 you can use conditionals as part of the XPath expressions to do this easily:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Copy elements, fixing up names and namespaces as required -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{if(substring(local-name(), 1, 2) = 'he')
                            then substring(local-name(), 3) else local-name()}"
                     namespace="{if(ancestor-or-self::InterChangeHead)
                                 then 'posten.xsd' else ''}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- specific template for InterChangeHead to add the (unused) xsi
         namespace declaration -->
    <xsl:template match="InterChangeHead">
      <InterChangeHead xmlns="posten.xsd"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </InterChangeHead>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove type attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@type"/>

    <!-- Remove unnecessary elements -->
    <xsl:template match="heXmlnsxsi" />
    <xsl:template match="heXmlns" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have added a specific template to declare the `xsi` namespace on `InterChangeHead`, though I'm not sure why it's necessary to include that declaration as it isn't used anywhere in the output XML document.  If it turns out not to be necessary you can simply remove the `<xsl:template match="InterChangeHead">` altogether, as the template matching `*` will also handle `InterChangeHead`, setting the namespace correctly.

Comment: Why is template `<xsl:template match="@* | text()">` needed?

Comment: @MarkVeenstra I suppose technically it isn't since the XML you're processing as input doesn't have any attributes (apart from the `tag` ones you are ignoring anyway) and the behaviour of that template on `text()` nodes is the same as the default.  Habit, I think, I always tend to start from an identity template...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the namespace for each element node, so change the template

```
<!-- Correct InterChangeHead element -->
<xsl:template match="InterChangeHead">
    <xsl:element name="InterChangeHead" namespace="posten.xsd">     
        <!-- Copy childs -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<!-- Correct InterChangeHead element and descendants -->
<xsl:template match="InterChangeHead | InterChangeHead//*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="posten.xsd">     
        <!-- Copy childs -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a complete stylesheet that simplifies the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Correct InterChangeHead element -->
    <xsl:template match="InterChangeHead | InterChangeHead//*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="posten.xsd">     
            <!-- Copy childs -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Rename elements beginning with "he" to elements without the "he" -->
    <xsl:template match="InterChangeHead//*[substring(local-name(), 1, 2) = 'he']" priority="5">
                <xsl:element name="{substring(local-name(), 3)}" namespace="posten.xsd">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove type attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@type"/>

    <!-- Remove unnecessary elements -->
    <xsl:template match="heXmlnsxsi" priority="6"/>
    <xsl:template match="heXmlns" priority="6"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```